# rails _4.2.11.1_ new does not load 'sqlite3'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm new to rails and was trying with rvm

```
rvm use 2.4.1
rails _4.2.11.1_ new hello_app
cd hello_app
rails s
```

which works with Rails 5 but fails with rails 4 and ruby 2.4.1 on my Mac

```
Gem::LoadError (Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).):
  activerecord (4.2.11.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec'
```

My Gemfile which is what rails new generated without comments

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.2.11.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
runtimes

gem 'jquery-rails'
more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'spring'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just because rails can't find exact version of gem needed, please provide version explicitly as below,

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
```

You can find reference [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d9601fd622a08b8ef5346c10f00fb13328d34d76#diff-1b086e9c0c1a6b852fda7b3542d6957b)

If it does not work, vary version and try as `gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.0'` in gemfile.

Comment: Thank you @ray you are awesome!